# Objeto JQUERY com string dinâmica

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Tenho um for() que adiciona alguns elementos na div#chat_box de acordo com o JSON retornado num AJAX.
Só que eu gostaria de ver quantos elementos com o data-identity iguais aos retornados no JSON existem.
Então eu fiz assim:

```js
// AJAX -> SUCCESS: FUNCTION(data){
// data É RETORNADO EM JSON
for( var i = 0; i < data.msgs; i++){
          
       if($('.msg[data-identity=' + data[i]['identity'] + ']').lenght){
           $('#chat_box').append('<div data-identity="' + data[i]['identity'] + '" class="msg user_' + data[i]['time'] + '"><span>'+ data[i]['nick'] + ': </span>' + data[i]['contente'] +'</div)'); 
       }  
}
//}
```

Só que não funciona e eu acho que é por conta dessa linha:

```
if($('.msg[data-identity=' + data[i]['identity'] + ']').lenght){
```

Mas eu não sei como posso colocar um parâmetro dinâmico (data[i]['identity']) no objeto jquery ($('.msg...'])), não funciona da forma que coloquei.

Alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: Não deu pra entender direito sua duvida, você precisa verificar se o elemento $('.msg[data-identity=' + data[i]['identity'] + ']') é mesmo do que esta no json ? ou se tem a mesma quantidade desse elemento do que tem dentro do json ? tenta descrever um pouco melhor o que é o problema

Comment: Basicamente eu quero saber se eu posso usar o objeto jquery dessa forma $('.msg[data-identity=' + data[i]['identity'] + ']') ou eu não posso por uma variável ali dentro

Comment: A sintaxe tá errada. O correto seria: `$('.msg[data-identity="' + data[i]['identity'] + '"]').length`

Comment: Pode sim, inclusive, dependendo de como estiver seu json esse código está certo, por isso pedi pra colocar um pedaço do json na pergunta, mas deve ser o erro na sintaxe, ps: o comentário do dvd deve resolver)

Comment: dvd posta como resposta :)

Comment: obrigado a todos.